# Input box not prefilling with "value" but works with placeholder

Tags: html, css

```
<input *ngIf="authService.user$ | async as user" type="text" id="nane" name="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name" [ngClass] = "{'error': isInvalid('name')}" **value = {{user.name}} />**
```

Hi, I'm trying to get my input box to default to the user's name however when I use value it doesn't work but other commands work like if I'm using placeholder, it'll use the user.name value. In the value's case, it just stays empty.

Comment: removing python tag since this is not a python question

Comment: I haven't used angular since v4 but I recall having to use `ng-model` for the default value.

Comment: I think [(ngModel)]="user.name" would work if user.name is defined as a property in your component

Comment: @GGizmos thanks, that worked!